# Write into re-opend NetCDF4 file

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, netcdf4

I'm trying to write numbers into an array with an unlimited dimensions. The file I've created is structured like this :

```
import netCDF4 as nc4

rootgrp = nc4.Dataset("test.nc",'a',format="NETCDF4")
mgrp= rootgrp.createGroup('Flex')
mgrp.createDimension('pv',None)
mgrp.createDimension('s',4)
a = mgrp.createVariable('fill',"f8",('pv','s'))
rootgrp.close()
```

Now I'm trying to fill this array like this :

```
while i<10:
    f = nc4.Dataset("test.nc",'r+',format="NETCDF4")
    fgrp= f.groups['Flex']
    fgrp['fill'][i][0] = i
    print(fgrp['fill'][i][:])
    f.groups['Flex'].variables['fill'][i][3] = i
    f.close()
    i=i+1
```

But I'm always getting a 'dimension out of bounds' error even though it's telling me that I've no dimension limit. Even if I use an array with fixed 100x4 dimension i still get the same error.

Would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback? It's not clear from your question what line is producing the error.

Answer (score 0):

This line is the problem:

```
fgrp['fill'][i][0] = i
```

`fgrp['fill'][i]` gets the ith row from the 'fill' variable. It then *immediately* tries to index into that row with `[0]`, which errors out because there's nothing in that row. To solve this problem, do the indexing in one step instead:

```
fgrp['fill'][i, 0] = i
```